# Log4Net and ElasticSearch - Multiple Indexes

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, log4net, log4net-appender

I am using log4net with an ElasticsearchAppender.
Now I would like to add another appender of ElasticSearch but with another index. 
What I did for now is:

```
<appender name="ElasticSearchAppender" type="log4net.ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchAppender, log4net.ElasticSearch">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date - %level - %message %property{label} %property{mstimeload} %property{applicationid} %property{page} 
           %property{ipclient} %property{browser} %property{browsersignature} %property{appversion} %property{sessionuniquecodetag} %property{globalcountertailsloaded} 
           %property{ipserveraddress}" />
  </layout>
  <connectionString value="Server=myip;Index=log;Port=9200;rolling=true"/>
  <lossy value="true" />
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="INFO"/>
  </evaluator>
</appender>
<appender name="ElasticSearchAppenderClient" type="log4net.ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchAppender, log4net.ElasticSearch">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date - %level - %message %property{label} %property{applicationid} %property{ipclient} %property{browser} %property{browserversione} %property{browsersignature}"/>
  </layout>
  <connectionString value="Server=myip;Index=logclient;Port=9200;rolling=true"/>
  <lossy value="true" />
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="INFO"/>
  </evaluator>
</appender>
```

Then on the server side I have

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("ElasticSearchAppender");
private static readonly log4net.ILog logclient = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("ElasticSearchAppenderClient");
```

The problem is when I add the values of the properties. because what I do is for example:

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["label"] = label;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ipclient"] = ipclient;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["applicationid"] = applicationid;
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["page"] = page;
...
log.Info(ex);
```

for the first log and

```
 log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["label"] = label;
 log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["browser"] = browser;
 log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["browserversion"] = browserversion;
 ...
 logclient.Info("");
```

But then in the log with index `logclient` I find the properties of the index `log` and viceversa. I would like instead to have two different and separate log indexes with different properties for each index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution.
In the web.config I did like this:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="ElasticSearchAppender" type="log4net.ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchAppender, log4net.ElasticSearch">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date %level %c{1} %c{2}" />
    </layout>
    <connectionString value="Server=localhost;Index=log;Port=9200;rolling=true"/>
    <lossy value="false" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
            <threshold value="ALL" />
    </evaluator>
    <bufferSize value="100" />
</appender>
<appender name="ElasticSearchAppenderClient" type="log4net.ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchAppender, log4net.ElasticSearch">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date %level %c{1} %c{3}" />
    </layout>
    <connectionString value="Server=localhost;Index=logclient;Port=9200;rolling=true"/>
    <lossy value="false" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
            <threshold value="ALL" />
    </evaluator>
    <bufferSize value="100" />
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearchAppender" />
</root>
<logger name="ElasticSearchAppenderClient" additivity="False"> <!-- additivity="False" VERY IMPORTANT!! -->
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearchAppenderClient" />
</logger>
</log4net>
```

And then I have created two different classes one for each Index and then I pass this class to my log:

```
private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("ElasticSearchAppender");
private static readonly ILog _logclient = LogManager.GetLogger("ElasticSearchAppenderClient");

Log thislog = new Log ();
thislog.label = "log";
thislog.mstime = 1;
_log.Error(thislog);

LogClient thislogc = new LogClient();
thislogc.label = "logclient";
thislogc.browser = 2;
_logclient.Error(thislogc);
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are logging directly from your app into Elasticsearch to a single index `logclient`.

You could create two named loggers with separate indices, and the use the loggers appropriately throughout your code.

You also might want to consider changing the `type` instead of the index.

Also you might want to consider using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash). While it is another service you'll be responsible for, it can bring a lot to the table such as routing logs to indices and types or ip to geo_hash conversion.

Lastly, I switched from Log4net to [Logary](https://github.com/logary/logary) over a year ago to improve the integration with Logstash/Elasticsearch and have been extremely satisfied.